# how DNS resolve automatic again

Tags: dns

I have a server. Coming request all here and changed my server. All Users still requesting old server. beacuse they using old dns record. I want to remove dns record all users automatic. I have a idea. But I dont know it will work.

IDEA:
if My old server return response status code 404 or 400, I think all users try to dns resolve

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the clients are still using the old DNS record because of the local client-side DNS cache.

The cache entries should have a TTL and the issue should resolve itself when the cached DNS entries expire and DNS is resolved to the new address.